# How invert this formula with % operator

Tags: c#, sequence, formula

I have a semaphore variable with 5 states.

I can increase the state using this cicle

```
X = (X + 1) % 5
```

> For X = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} generate {1, 2, 3, 4, 0}.

But if I try go in the other direction decreasing the state, doesn't bring the right result.

```
X = (X - 1) % 5
```

> For X = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} generate {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3} insted of {4, 0, 1, 2, 3}

For example in excel if you try `=MOD(-1;5)` you get 4.

Comment: In C# '%' returns the remainder not the modulus, so I think i will always be positive.

Comment: @Matt: the remainder of a negative argument is still negative.

Comment: @Matt MOD in excel is the remainder, http://tipsforspreadsheets.com/microsoft_excel_2003_function_0019.html

Comment: Wouldn't the opposite direction be {4, 3, 2, 1, 0}?

Comment: @Andreas: by 'oposite direction' he means the direction of moving the numbers, not the sequence increment

Comment: @Andreas I just try to write the f(x) for same domain.

Comment: Here reversing means directional movement of original set if +1 leads to clock wise movement, then -1 should lead to anti clock wise, which was was not happening in the original solution

Comment: @Matt now after I read Servy comment I undestand your comment. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
X = (X - 1) % 5
```

use

```
X = (X + 4) % 5
```

which is the short form of

```
X = (X - 1 + 5) % 5
```

or generally

```
X = (X - 1 + n) % n
```

This ensures that the argument in `()` is always positive - so the division remainder stays also positive.

Comment: That is, Weird how Excel can handle negative numbers but C# doesnt.

Comment: Ideal formula would be X = (X - 1 + an) % n, where a is a constant whole number to ensure that final result is always positive post calculating modulus, if we have one of the number as -15, then we need multiple of n, which is 5 to ensure the positive result

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: That's correct. But `X = (X - 1 + n) % n` will do it because I assume that `X` is always calulated from the last `X`, and the formula only subtracts 1 (not a number greater that n)

Comment: @Joe in this case yes, I was talking about a more generic situation

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: Agreed.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza [Remainder and modulas aren't the same operation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx), even though many people conflate the two.  In C# you're using the remainder operator, and in Excel you're using the Modulus operator.  That different operators do different things is expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that [C# supports remainder operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) instead of modulus operator.

If your `x` is always in the range between `0` and `n-1` then the other simpler solutions suffice. If you want a method that works for any `x` then something more complicated is necessary.

```
static int modulus(int x, int n)
{
    return ((x % n) + n) % n;
}
```

The first remainder operation converts the value to the `-n+1 ... n-1` range. Once we add `n` we obtain always positive value. The final remainder operation then provides the expected result.

Comment: C# *has no modulus operator*. It has a *remainder* operator, but no *modulus* operator.  You can create a function that performs a modulus, possibly using the remainder operator to implement it, as you've done.  (You could also implement the reverse, if you needed it.)  Also note that the inner `% n` is entirely superfluous.

Comment: @Servy You are right. I've fixed my answer. Thank you. By the way, the inner `% n` is not superfluous if we want to correctly calculate modulus of any negative number. If we only have `(x + n) % n` and we have `x = -8` and `n = 3` then `(-8 + 3) % 3 = (-5) % 3 = -2` and it is not the right result. The proposed expression gives the correct result `1` instead.